# How to print the line from a file that contains the matching characters in the pattern

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to print all the lines from a file that has the same characters of the matching pattern.
Here is my pattern -

```
CurrentPrincipal[MRC]
CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation
```

In the file I have the lines like the below ones

```
823,agg.listgroup,CurrentPrincipal[MRC],CompanyElementDefinition
d4f170,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MRC][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
1097,agg.listgroup,CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation,CompanyElementDefinition
c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
8798c3,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MailingAddressStreetLine1][*],CompanyElementDefinition
```

I am iterating my pattern and printing its matching lines from the file. What I need is, when I iterate my pattern `CurrentPrincipal[MRC]` I should get only its matching line

`d4f170,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MRC][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition`

and when the pattern is `CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation` I should get only

`c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition`

My requirement is to ignore the `[` `]` from the line while matching pattern.
I have tried my best to put my issue affront. Do let me know if anything else is needed from me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you need. Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input file, *including both desired and undesired lines*, and then show us the output you would expect from that example.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want the `[` and `]` characters to be treated literally rather than as indicating a character range. You can do that by *escaping* them:

```
grep 'CurrentPrincipal\[LegalEventAssociation\]' file
```

Ex. given:

```
$ cat file
823,agg.listgroup,CurrentPrincipal[MRC],CompanyElementDefinition
d4f170,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MRC][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
1097,agg.listgroup,CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation,CompanyElementDefinition
c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
8798c3,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MailingAddressStreetLine1][*],CompanyElementDefinition
```

then

```
$ grep 'CurrentPrincipal\[LegalEventAssociation\]' file
c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
```

Alternatively use the `-F` or `--fixed-strings` option to tell grep to treat all characters literally:

```
$ grep -F 'CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation]' file
c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
```

Comment: This is fine but my search pattern is `CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation` and I cannot modify it to include the escape sequence. All I want is like grep or awk command that will print the line `c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Typ‌​e][*],CompanyElement‌` when the search pattern is `CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation`. While searching the file with this pattern I should tell the command to ignore the brackets of that line.

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy please see my updated answer using `grep -F`. Also, it shouldn't be necessary to iterate over a file containing search patterns - there is ` -f` option (lower case `f`) to read patterns directly from a file.

Comment: Thanks for updating but the pattern what I have mentioned in my question does not have any brackets. It is just `CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation`

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy then it seems you will need to **either** add the characters to your search pattern **or** remove them from the file you are searching

Comment: I am afraid I can't do both. This is what driving me crazy since this morning.

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy,  Do you have a policy against modifying them or is it a principal thing?  Because it's not impossible to do so the only thing stopping you from doing it is yourself -- or possibly some weird company policy?   You shouldn't approach automation with a "can't do" attitude.  "Whether you think you can, or you think you can't...you're right." -Henry Ford

Comment: Also if you are receiving bad input from some upstream application, really the correct thing to do would be to fix that application rather than massage it's output, but I digress.

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy you need to explain your restrictions clearly in your question. Tell us what you can do and what you cannot do. But if you can't change the search pattern and can't change the input, you can't do anything. So please edit your question and explain what options you do have.

Answer (score 1):

[grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) seems to do what you want.

```
grep 'word' filename
```

Will print every line in the file 'filename' that contains 'word'.

Comment: I have tried this already but if you see, my file has `1097,agg.listgroup,CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation,CompanyElementDefinition
c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition` and I need only `c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition` . The line I need contains brackets and I want to ignore that while searching.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following, the file output appears in next line in the file after pattern search line.

```
sed -n '/CurrentPrincipal\[MRC\]/p' filename | sed -n '2p'
```

Output

```
d4f170,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MRC][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
```

---

```
sed -n '/CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation/,+1p' l.txt | sed -n '2p'
```

Output

```
c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
```